# How do I reverse a list in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I want a list in a list like this [1,2] list in lst to be reversed :

```
Lst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]


Input: Lst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]


Output: [[2,1],[4,3],[6,5]]
```

Please help
[extra words because I entered less than 220 words]:plz help plzhelpplzhelpplzhelpplzhelp

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this, and this will work for variable lengths of lists as well:

```py
lst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
[x[::-1] for x in lst]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
```

Comment: Explain "something like", that is called slicing using the third parameter which the incremental param

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sublist method of the list in Python.
Something like:

```py
Lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
reversed_Lst = [[sublist[1], sublist[0]] for sublist in Lst]
print(reversed_Lst)
```

*Note: This solution works for the inner list with 2 elements as mentioned in the question. Please refer to other answers for generic solutions.*

Comment: This works but only because the inner lists all contain exactly two elements

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension shown by Suraj Shourie works well, but we can also do this with:

```
list(map(list, map(reversed, lst)))
```

- Mapping `reversed` to each element in the list will give us an iterable object that will yield `list_reverseiterator` objects.
- We can map `list` to each of these objects to get an iterable object that will yield lists.
- Finally we can turn that iterable object into a list, which gets us to:

```
[[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `reversed()` function:

```
Lst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

Lst = [[*reversed(i)] for i in Lst]

print(Lst)

# [[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
```

or use `reverse()` method if you want to modify the list in place:

```
Lst = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]

for i in Lst: i.reverse()

print(Lst)

#[[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
```